# AS3 Each Time Score Reaches

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay so on a Flash project stage there is a dynamic text box which keeps score of whatever activity is happening on the stage...mouse clicks, collisions...whatever...

I want it so that each time the dynamic text box (score box) hits 2000 (e.g. 2000, 4000, 6000)...each time we hit a 2000 multiple a hidden movie clip becomes visible...otherwise the movie clip is hidden.

Thanks all for considering a reply...this is what I have...it works fine but I don't know how to make it so that each time it adds on 2000 points the movie clip 'saleTag' will show.

```
if (cashBox.text == "2000")
    {
        saleTag.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        saleTag.visible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to employ some logic. When the score is 2500, should your hidden MC be visible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Read some books. E.g. Colin Moock. If you have troubles at this point, you need to get more basics.
2. Don't store data in textfield, it is usually used to display data:) Use vars instead:

`private var counter:int=0;`

3. Make a function which will increase the counter, check the conditions and manage the visibility of your movieclip.

   ```
   private function increaseCounter():void 
       {
           counter++;

           if (Math.floor(counter/2000)==counter/2000) 
           {
               saleTag.visible = true;
           }
           else 
           {
               saleTag.visible = false;
           }
       }
   ```

Call it each time you need to increase a counter.

4. Fine tuning. Remove the "Else" branch and use timer\delayed call to set `saleTag.visible = false;`.

Comment: Although the answer itself is relevant and has valid points, I'd say it's bad. See, you're trying to compare an `int` to a `Number` which is bad practice, as `Number` is a floating-point, even if you divide 2000 by 2000, and may misbehave if implemented differently at levels where you don't have control as a developer.

Comment: More, there are different meanings of "hits" as OP said, usually this means "equal or greater", as in "Stock price on Y hits a new record". I expect OP wants to have a `saleTag` MC visible when his game's player should be able to buy something, which is worth 2000, but if `counter` is greater than 2000, that tag would be hidden.

Comment: Yep, but in this particular case this code does exactly what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't count with cashBox.text which is a `String`. You should first count your events with an `integer` variable (n), then test this variable to know if it's a multiple of 2000,
and convert it to `String` in your textField cashBox.

```
saleTag.visible = false;
var n:int = 0;
const LIM:int = 2000;

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    n++;
    cashBox.text = String(n);
    saleTag.visible = (n%LIM == 0) ? true : false;
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHandler);
```